# "terminating" array in C

Tags: arrays, c

if my program needs an int array of size of at most 10 and my user is given the option to "terminate" the data set when entering -1, what are some ways i can acheive this?

By "terminating", I am referring to if my user enters -1 while inputting the values in the array, the array stopps scanning user input values immediately and returns the values that were entered previously, discarding -1.

The array size can be at most 10, but i do not know how to process the array when my user enters less than 10 values.

Example:

```
Enter data -> 1 2 3 4 5 -1
data[10] contains {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}

Enter data -> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
data[10] contains {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}

Enter data -> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 -1
data[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}
```

I'm not allowed to use break statements. Right now I can only think of searching for -1 and turning it and the reset of the values into 0. This is what i have so far:

```
int getValues(int arr[])
{
  int loop; // used to iterate through for loop
  int terminate; // used to iterate through for loop when user terminates data set
  loop = 0;
  terminate = 0;

  printf("Enter 10 integer values -> ");
  for (loop = 0; loop < 10; loop++)
  {
    scanf("%d", &arr[loop]);

    if (arr[loop] == -1)
    {
      arr[loop] = 0;
      for (terminate = loop; terminate < 10; terminate++)
      {
        arr[terminate] = 0;
      }
    }
  }
  printf("\n");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "terminate". Your code overwrites all subseqzuent and noninited values with a magic 0. I feel that is not what you want, but if your code does not show what you want then you need to explain in prose. Consider showing several triples of sample input, desired result and result you get. Make sure that you have triples for each relevant case and some edge cases of weird input and undesired results.

Comment: Side issues: Consider avoiding magic numbers like 10, -1, 0. Add a size parameter. Do not ignore scanf return value.

Comment: You need to indent your code. Unindented code is hard to understand eve for us.

Comment: You cannot change the size of an array referenced by a parameter (and not of any other array either). That might be the answer to your question. Please confirm it is what you ask about or explain in more detail. And even writing to an array without knowing the size is unwise.

Comment: You need to store the number of elements of your array somehow.

Comment: If you do not want to change the size then you probably want to somehow process only the number of entered values before termination. For that you can either store the size/number (as Jaberwocky said) or you can store the magic termination value and continue using it not only for entering but also for later processing. Please explain why that is not an option. Using 0 instead of -1 for unused fields seems risky, because using -1 for terminating entering seems to imply that 0 is a valid value.

Comment: What is the desired behaviour for `Enter data -> 1 2 0 0 0 -1`?

Comment: I am not allowed to change the size of the array since i can only take in at most 10 values. as for storing the magic termination, I've tried doing that but once my program reaches 10 values, it does not process/ print out

Comment: In that case you probably want to show THAT code as a [mre], describe the observed behaviour and ask about that.

Comment: the array will contain values {1, 2, 0, 0, 0} when -1 is entered, we do not need to fill the data set to capacity

Comment: If you are not allowed to and do not want to change the size of the array (wise) then please do not discuss changing array size. Instead discuss "processing fewer than 10 entered values".

Comment: "an int array of size of at most 10" Then, i.e. if the referenced array can be shorter than 10, you definitly need to know the size within your function and NOT write beyond it, ever. Introduce another paremeter `int size` for that.

Comment: "my program needs an int array of size of at most 10" Your program does not need it, it obviously already has it and references it with the first parameter to your function. Your function now has to be able to handle differently sized arrays which it does not create itself, i.e. function needs to know the size and only another parameter can provide that info.

Comment: then what will i be using the **int size** parameter for? will i be creating another array?

Comment: Size parameter is for NOT writing beyond available size. If the size is <10 you cannot write more values and hence cannot allow users to enter more (or have to ignore them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want this: We stop the loop as soon as the user has entered -1 but we simply store that -1 in the array and we use that -1 one as terminator.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int getValues(int arr[])
{
  int loop; // used to iterate through for loop

  printf("Enter 10 integer values -> ");
  for (loop = 0; loop < 10; loop++)
  {
    scanf("%d", &arr[loop]);

    if (arr[loop] == -1)
    {
      loop = 10 - 1;     // simulate a break
    }
  }
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}


int main()
{
  int arr[10];
  getValues(arr);

  // print array values and stop at the -1 terminator
  for (int i = 0; i < 10 && arr[i] != -1; i++)
    printf("arr[%d] = %d\n", i, arr[i]);
}
```

Another possibility is to store the size of the array:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int getValues(int arr[], int *size)
{
  int loop; // used to iterate through for loop

  printf("Enter 10 integer values -> ");
  for (loop = 0; loop < 10; loop++)
  {
    scanf("%d", &arr[loop]);

    if (arr[loop] == -1)
    {
      *size = loop;      // store the size
      loop = 10 - 1;     // simulate a break
    }
  }

  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}


int main()
{
  int arr[10];
  int size;
  getValues(arr, &size);
  // now size contains the number of elements of the array
  
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    printf("arr[%d] = %d\n", i, arr[i]);
}
```

There are still issues with this code:

- the return value of `scanf` is ignored
- there is no check for out of bounds array access, **In other words**, the user can enter more than 10 numbers and thus write beyond the array bounds which will lead to *undefined behaviour* (google that term).
- the hard coded value `10` is all over the place